# Question for a collage maker app

Tags: gui-design, guidance, style-guide

I am creating a collage maker app for Windows Phone. I have a simple yet intriguing question in mind.

Being a student developer, I cannot support both borderless collages and those with borders (shortage of time).

Given the case, should I create the app with borders between the pictures or should the collage be thrown in borderless.

Which one will be better?

Thanks!

EDIT: Consider these as an example:

Borderless: [image: Borderless]

With Borders : [image: With Borders]

**could you please also suggest how thick should the border be?** Is the thickness correct in the second pic above or should it be thinner?

Comment: Both of these mean the same thing: "I cannot support both borderless collages and those without borders." Can you clarify what you mean? Give examples of what kind of collage you're talking about? Perhaps some of your own thinking about why border or borderless is better?

Comment: @DrewBeck I apologize for the confusion, I have edited my description. Have also added pics to describe what I am saying. Can you please suggest something now?

Comment: I'm a big fan of the border look. you can always release the borderless option as a feature later.

Comment: I see, how thick should the border be? Is the correct like in the second pic above? Or should I go with a thinner version?

Comment: This isn't really a UX question.

Comment: Not sure where else to ask it though..  Can you please answer anyway?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go with a thin border. Don't hint to the user whether or not you'll have borders. Just do it.

Comment: Hey, should it be thinner than the one in the second example pic above?  Half of it would be alright?

Comment: 1 pixel, exactly as shown in the first picture.

Comment: They asked for an approach and/or what to do regarding a border. Answer: Go with a thin border. How and why is this response not an answer?

Comment: @MickaelCaruso: It's not a particularly *good* answer, it's just a personal preference suggestion. You've provided no reasoning, no explanation or anything other than personal preference. If OP decides to take your approach and is questioned on it the only answer he has is *'I did it because one person on the internet thought it was a nice idea'*. It'd be far better if your answer gave some solid reasoning behind it as that'd lend it some credibility.

Comment: So I learn there's unspoken rules here - don't post unless you can back it up with professional research. I know my post was short because the question was simple. Now when I cite personal experiences and why such a UI confuses me an d offer suggestions of what I've done, it's not allowed. SMH.

Comment: @MickaelCaruso, it is not an "unspoken rule". It is very prominent seen in other answers, expressed in the FAQ and discussed on the UX meta site. Good UX is not about personal opinion, it is about how people actually behave (we have a lot of psychologists in the field). Why should I "go with a thin border"? Why should I "hint to the user"? What are the UX implications if I "just do it"? If your answer comes purely from personal experience, discuss that experience.

Answer (score 0):

Purely aesthetically I like the balance of the one with borders. This provides some breathing room for one image to transition into another. The one with thin lines looks awkward because those pictures don't really work when fit together.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.. Just one more question, how thick should the border be.  Is it fine like in the second picture above, or should it be thinner than that?

Answer (score 0):

Whether an image (or group of images) has a border or not is highly dependent on a) the images in question and b) the aesthetic opinion of the artist.

So, ideally it's an option, and adjustable at that. But it sounds like you have to pick one or the other. In that case, as you can see by the answers thus far: it doesn't matter as everyone is going to have a different opinion.

Unless you can ask the users of the app and you can come to a conclusion that one is significantly better than the other, it doesn't matter. Just pick whichever you think looks better.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I'll try and come to a conclusion soon.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking from the product perspective, i would suggest break it down as a feature and its components and define priorities within these feature backlogs. That's how it is done with good product development life cycles. 
I would break it down like:

1. Having no border
2. Ability to have border and define thickness and color

I would consider the border and its ability to be user defined as the pictures will make this decision subjective to the user and you cannot have an objective answer like #000000 and 1px thick would always fit for everyones collage!

Hope you find your way out of this.. Good luck with your app!

Cheers,
Nishant